# Setting background for selected item in BootStrap Menu bar similar to parent Nav option in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the bootstrap navbar I wanted to navbar menu options to have the features of active class when it is selected.

```
<div class="navtop">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPL</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="mainpage.php">Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="createteam.php">Create Team </a></li>
            <li><a href="pastscores.php">Past Scores</a></li>
          </ul>

    </nav>
</div>
```

Currently when I hover over the nav list it changes color as per the changes I made in bootstrap.theme.css but it does not remain when it is the active menu.Please help me out with this.

These are the changes I made to bootstrap.theme.css

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
.navbar-nav> li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav> li > a:focus {
background-color: #e8e8e8;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,   from(#3c3c3c), to(#e8e8e8));
background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5', endColorstr='#ffe8e8e8', GradientType=0);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: you are closing <nav> but where you have started it?

Comment: For me its ok. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/pov2jp22/ then what is the issue?

Comment: Leo , I had replaced the nav with a div thinking that was the reason it was not working. and yes its working fine in the jsfiddle, but at my end hover is working fine but the background is not staying if I move the cursor away.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with your css class, but whenever you click on any of the menu, assign new class (suppose `active`) through jquery or javascript to that respective `<a>` tag and write a style for a the same class (ie `active`)

Comment: Hi Trimanta, I was trying your method to add a class on clicking but its not working for me not sure why .https://jsfiddle.net/pov2jp22/12/ as the same thing is done by another person http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/ which works fine. :(

Comment: Hello, https://jsfiddle.net/pov2jp22/12/ is not working because, there is no jquery library added. jquery library needs to be added to run your js code successfully.